# EXCEPTION_ACCES_VIOLATION

Tags: gpu, drivers

I was trying to export a few thousand stimuli manipulated along some dimension in one go. This worked fine for batch sizes of 17 000, but when I increased the batch size, Blender crashed. When I try to open Blender the control panel opens, gives a 'EXCEPTION_ACCES_VIOLATION' error, writes a 'blender.crash.txt', and the command center closes again.

I have tried: to run Blender from the administrative mode, to update my drivers, to reinstall it and its portable sibling, and to downgrade the blender version, but none work.

Since Blender worked before, I think it should work again, but I don't see why it doesn't.
People that know something about this, please help; my product specifications are:
Blender version: 2.93.5, Windows version: Windows 10 Pro version 1909, Graphical driver: Intel(R) UHD graphics 630 and AMD radeon RX 550. If you need anything else, please ask!

Comment: Try rebooting your PC!

Comment: Currently Blender has an upper limit for objects (about 50k), it will not tell you if you're getting close, it will just become unholy sluggish and then crash. IDK what stimuli are, but try to keep the object count below 30k (particles aren't objects)